# My Command Prompt and Turbo C++ 3.0 won't go FULL SCREEN, why?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate with 'Pentium Dual Core CPU E5200 @2.50GHz' and 'Intel G33/G31 Express Chipset Family' as display adapter. I have 2 GB RAM. When I press alt+enter in cmd or turbo c++, it says "This system does not support Full Screen Mode". I am using 1600 * 900 screen resolution. Can anyone tell how to solve this problem.

Comment: You're trying to use a program from 1991. In an operating system released in 2006. I personally wouldn't expect it to work at all, so you're kinda lucky. In fact, since it's most likely a 16-bit program, it probably *won't* work in 64-bit versions of Windows. You could try an emulator such as [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). I would kinda recommend using a newer C++ compiler/IDE, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install DOSBox

You will be able to get fullscreen. You will also be able to use TurboC graphics libraries

EDIT:

Also, you are using Windown 7 Ultimate

If you have enough bandwidth, install Windows XP mode. Its perfect for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Unless you give up Aero desktop experience and change the WDDM driver (Windows Vista Display Driver Model) to Windows XP compatible display driver, there is no easy way to enable a real, windowless full screen command prompt in Windows 7

Source: [here](http://www.walkernews.net/2009/11/22/enable-full-screen-command-prompt-window-persistently-in-windows-7/)

There is a trick mentioned further down the page that explains how to open CMD maximised each time.

> 1) Create a shortcut to cmd.exe and double click to open it.
>
> 2) Type
>   wmic and press ENTER to get Windows Management Instrumentation
>   Command-line utility running into an interactive mode.
>
> 3) Click the maximize button to get a real full screen window of
>   Command Prompt. With Windows 7 default installation setting, you can
>   also click the Command Prompt window title bar and drag it up to the
>   edge of Desktop to get the same maximized window.
>
> 4) Right click the maximized Command Prompt window title bar and
>   select “Properties”. In the Properties dialog box, tick the “Quick
>   edit mode” check-box followed by clicking OK button. This step makes
>   Windows 7 “remember” to maximize Command Prompt to this particular
>   full screen window mode, each time you double click the cmd.exe
>   shortcut created in step 1!
>
> 5) Close the Command Prompt window (by click the X button or execute
>   exit command twice to exit from WMIC as well as cmd.exe).
>
> Now, double click the same cmd.exe shortcut again, you should see
>   Windows 7 open Command Prompt in the same maximized, full screen
>   window mode again :-)

Comment: Hey thanks, the trick works ! You are a Genius. But there is another problem. I have Turbo C++ 3.0 and I want it to run in the FUll SCREEN. The solution you provided works for Command Prompt only, but not for Turbo C++. You've got solution for this too, I guess. Please let me know.

Comment: Run turbo C in the command prompt.

Comment: I checked a website, I'm afraid the genius title may be a bit premature :-(